# DrawerNavigator: DrawerItem other than screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-navigation

I want a simple functionality of logging out from drawer item press. For that i have done this:-

```
const HomeNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
    {
       Splash: { screen: SplashScreen }
    }
)
```

This adds an item in drawer and on clicking it app navigates to splash screen. But with this method i could not achieve whole functionality of logging out. i.e:-

1. Clearing the screen stack so that on back press app shouldn't go back to screen with drawer.
2. App should navigate from splash to login screen after logging out.

My above solution not letting me do both these things. Is there a better way to achieve my requirement?

**Update**

My Navigation structure so far is somewhat like this:-

```
StackNavigator(
   Splash: {screen: SplashScreen},
   Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
   Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
)

HomeNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
   Logout: {screen: SplashScreen}
)

HomeScreen{
   render(){
       return <HomeNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
   }
}
```

You can see i am using `SplashScreen` in both navigators. In stack it's the first screen while in drawer it's used for logging out. but when i navigate from drawer screen to splash i lose the `StackNavigator` that i created before for splash to login navigation. Can you suggest me any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can call this function in the `componentWillMount(){}` of the Splash Screen:

```
clearStack = (routeToGo) =>  {
    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: routeToGo })
        ]
    })
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
}
```

Importing {NavigationActions} from react-navigation.
You can also create a custom drawer navigator by using the [contentComponent](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer#Example) prop in the DrawerNavigatorConfig, in which you can change the onPress of the navItems to do whatever you want, like calling the function to clear your stacks.

UPDATE: on your Splash Screen

```
componentWillMount(){
   this.clearStack('Login')
}
```

Comment: Oh My bad. By seeing your answer, i just realized that this is already being handled. you answered half of my question. How will i navigate from splash to login? i will update my question with more info for my 2nd half.

Comment: I think a good solution might be adding the DrawerNavigator as a screen to your StackNavigator, then you won't 'lose' it.